# Is there a library for python that allows conversions from markdown to html (including lists)?

Tags: python, html, markdown

Is there a library for python that allows conversions from markdown to html (including lists)?

I have tried using two libraries: markdown and markdown2
Both of these libraries take this input:
[image]

```
###Stepped
The translation will pause if:
- There are no translations for this word
- There are multiple translations for this word

And will ask you how to continue
```

and convert it to this:
[image]

```html
<h3>Stepped</h3>

<p>The translation will pause if:
- There are no translations for this word
- There are multiple translations for this word</p>

<p>And will ask you how to continue</p>
```

I'm looking for functionality similar to https://markdowntohtml.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a pretty standard feature.

The problem is likely your input. Add a blank line above the list:

```markdown
###Stepped
The translation will pause if:

- There are no translations for this word
- There are multiple translations for this word

And will ask you how to continue
```

I suggest also adding a blank line after the heading, and a space separating the hashes from the heading text:

```markdown
### Stepped

The translation will pause if:

- There are no translations for this word
- There are multiple translations for this word

And will ask you how to continue
```

This aids readability of the source code, which was an [explicit design consideration](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/):

> The overriding design goal for Markdown’s formatting syntax is to make it as readable as possible. The idea is that a Markdown-formatted document should be publishable as-is, as plain text, without looking like it’s been marked up with tags or formatting instructions.

The space between `###` and `Stepped` is also required in many specs and implementations, [including CommonMark](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#atx-headings), which is rapidly gaining traction:

> The opening sequence of `#` characters must be followed by spaces or tabs, or by the end of line.

Comment: This works perfectly. It's odd that PyCharm markdown rendering works differently to the markdown library

Comment: The original reference implementation lacked a spec and has a few undefined behaviours. Other implementations made slightly different decisions, and as a result some things don't work reliably across implementations. CommonMark is a pretty good reference spec these days.